# How to solve the error 'No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector ''

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am using Xcode 5

This is my AppDelegate.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;

@end
```

This is my AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize viewController = _viewController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
     // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
[self.viewController saveData];
     }

    - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [self.viewController loadData];
    }

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

@end
```

This is my ViewController.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

//some variables declared here

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, UINavigationBarDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>{
    //some outlets declared here
}

//some actions and - (void) declared here

- (NSString *) getFilePath;

- (void) saveData;

- (void) loadData;

@end
```

Beside the code `[self.viewController saveData]` and `[self.viewController loadData]` there's an error message:`'No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'saveData'` and `'No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'loadData'`.
What should I do?

Comment: Just update in your AppDelegate.h file, from UIViewController to ViewController. Which is your actual class name.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify class of UIViewController in your AppDelegate.h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

and add import statement in this file

```
#import "ViewController.h"
```

Comment: I followed your solution and those two error messages disappeared, but Apple Mach-O Linker Error appeared.

Comment: @홍승욱 what error message you have? Check, that you have not importing AppDelegate.h in ViewController.h / ViewController.m

Answer (score 1):

Your `viewController` is subclass of UIViewController class so there is not saveData/LoadData method.
The two method exists in your custom class - ViewController.

The solution is replace line in AppDelegate.h from:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIViewController *viewController;
```

to:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;
```

or cast viewController to ViewController every time you call saveData/loadData

Answer (score 0):

If the view controller in the app delegate is truly a `ViewController` object, then change the property to say so:
`@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;`

You will then also need the matching `@class` (.h) and `#import` (.m) statements.